# Excel formula to format different numbers

Tags: excel, formatting, numbers

I need your help on how to approach this problem.

I have a column exported that contains some information that i will need to make some calculations on.

Example

1,234,532.67

**2.345,43**

**2 345,43**

**2 345.43**

**65820,6**

1.435

123.45

12,534.34

1,343

2,435.45

321,45

1,234,532.67 some text

1.435 some text

123.45 some text

12,534.34 some text

1,343 some text

2,435.45 some text

321,45 some text

some text 1,234,532.67 some text

some text 1.435 some text

some text 123.45 some text

some text 12,534.34 some text

some text 1,343 some text

some text 2,435.45 some text

some text 321,45 some text

the result i want would be

1234532.67

1435.00

123.45

12534.34

1343.00

2435.45

321.45

Thank you very much

L.E. 
Sorry for the lack of info in my first approach, it was Friday and i struggled all day with this to make it work, as a last resort i decided to try to post here. Half-way writing the post i noticed that i was missing the bus home so i wrote what i could, saved and left.

I've updated the info in the example with another pain in the ass formatting problem. The data you see in the example and that i have to make some calculations on is exported from a tool, I've talked to the tool owners and the people that insert the data and it appears most of the info is automated or in good condition. There's just only one column with that kind of messed up formatting that is giving me headaches. The said column is inserted manually in the tool and we can't do anything to change that because people are not robots, they will make mistakes.

Thank you very much for all the replies.

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you run into problems? There are a variety of Excel formulas which will extract digits from a string.  There are also VBA options

Comment: Oh, and what rule are you using to decide if the comma represents a decimal or a thousands separator.  You have both types in your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a worksheet formula, so long as you are using the comma for thousands separator; and the dot for decimal.

```
=LOOKUP(9.9E+307,--MID(A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1& "0123456789")),seq))
```

where `seq` is a named formula that refers to:

```
=ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))
```

Note that your entries in `A7`, `A14` and `A21` are truncated at the comma.  All of your other entries use comma as the thousands separator, but there are only two digits following the comma in those entries.  If you are going to mix locales in the same data, you will need to develop unambiguous rules for defining which separator/decimal symbols to use where.  Otherwise, the data will be interpreted according to your current separator/decimal symbols.

[image]

**EDIT**

Given your comment below that the values will have mixed locale formatting, but decimals all have only two digits, you can try the following UDF.

It also uses Regular Expressions to

- Replace non-decimal separators
- Then replace the decimal separator with a `dot`, although one could use the locale instead.
- `Trim` any possible leading spaces

**EDIT 2:** *corrected regex to account for decimals with single digit*

---

```
Option Explicit
'Assumes decimals have two digits
' Should work so long as decimals do not have three digits

Function getNums(S As String) As Double
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Const sPat As String = "\D(?!(?:\d{1,2}|\d{4,})\b)"
    Dim sNum As String

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

'Replace everything except decimal separator
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    sNum = Trim(.Replace(S, "")) 'need to replace any leading space

    'replace decimal separator with dot
    .Pattern = "\D"
    getNums = CDbl(.Replace(sNum, "."))
End With
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: @GarysStudent It shows same issue as `A7`. Thanks for catching that. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thank you very much for your reply, i will try to implement it today, I will try to make it work for **2.345,43** also because i guess your solution will not do it. Thanks again

Comment: @RonRosenfeld found out 2 more formats with spaces instead of thousands separator :(

Comment: @AndreiMazilu With mixed locale formatting, given a value like `123,456`, how do you know if the comma represents a thousands separator or a decimal point?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld i don't know, that's why i'm assuming decimals have only 2 digits. I tried both UDFs but i can't make them work. I have x64 Office and i googled for some conversion from x86 UDF to x64 ... it was just a wild guess that got me nowhere...

Comment: @AndreiMazilu My last udf works on all the examples you provided. What does "can't make them work" mean?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you, it worked. I never used UDF before so first i saved the UDF in the PERSONAL macro file and it did not work on my specific workbook. Then i had the idea of saving the module directly on the workbook i'm working on and it worked. It worked on all cases but one, a new one that i did not see before ( 65820,6 ). I will try to modify your UDF to include that case also. Thanks again.

Comment: @AndreiMazilu A small change in the REGEX will take care of that.  Should be:  `\D(?!(?:\d{1,2}|\d{4,})\b)`  I will edit my UDF above. I never tested with just a single decimal digit before

Answer (score 1):

Try this small User Defined Function:

```
Public Function GetNumbers(rng As Range) As Double
    Dim s As String, L As Long, i As Long, temp As String
    Dim CH As String

    s = rng.Text
    L = Len(s)
    temp = ""

    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9]" Or CH = "." Then
            temp = temp & CH
        End If
    Next i

    GetNumbers = CDbl(temp)
End Function
```

With data in column **A**, place the functions in column **B** like:

[image]

and format the cells with two decimal places and no thousands separator.

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#1:**

another example:

[image]

**EDIT#2:**

This version of the code detects ASCII-39 characters in the string, and if found, replaces the comma with the period:

```
Public Function GetNumbers(rng As Range) As Double
    Dim s As String, L As Long, i As Long, temp As String
    Dim CH As String, tick As String

    s = rng.Text
    L = Len(s)
    temp = ""
    tick = Chr(39)
    If InStr(1, s, tick) > 0 Then
        s = Replace(s, ",", ".")
    End If

    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9]" Or CH = "." Then
            temp = temp & CH
        End If
    Next i

    GetNumbers = CDbl(temp)
End Function
```

Comment: What about "123'456,789"? Or any other locales?

Comment: @user6698332  I am sorry; I don't understand your question.

Comment: yeah, of course ;) Try on your code when `s = "123'456,789"`

Comment: @user6698332 see my **EDIT#1** .................the code ignores the comma and apostrophe-type characters along with all other letters and special characters **including the minus sign..................the only special character processed is the period**.

Comment: really, my `"123'456,789"` is `123456 + 0.789`

Comment: @user6698332  Very well............I will modify my code to look for the quote character, and if found, treat the comma as a decimal separator..............update will come in a few hours.

Comment: For a 6 digit number I do not believe it is possible to unambiguously determine the decimal versus thousands separator.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  You are 100% correct................my code always assumes that **123,456** is just a big integer with no decimal component.

Comment: That is why I would wait for clarification before going down this road.  I suspect the 321,45 is a typo, and should be 321.45.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Agreed.................poster want special handling of a string with ASCII-39, so I modified the UDF().

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for the replies guys. All the numbers have only 2 decimals as far as i'm concerned. so 123,45 it's the same for me as 123.45. My problem is now with 2.234,34. Thanks again guys.

Comment: @AndreiMazilu See my edit for an attempt at handling mixed locale formatting.